# how to send a message from inside a callback function with mongodb in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am coding a basic project manager, nothing fancy. I am writing the page where the project is created (with AngularJS) and am sending all the $scope to /create (the backend is Express.js). The router gets the JSON perfectly, and save it to a local MongoDB without problems.

My problem is that I want to set a message telling that the project was created successfully and send it back to AngularJS. This is my code.

**router.js**

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
   app.post('/create', function (req, res) {
      var create = require("./../scripts/create")(req, res, db);
      console.log(create);  //just for testing whether I can receive the message.
   });
}
```

**create.js**

```
module.exports = function(req, res, db) {
   db.collection('projects').insert(req.body.project, function(err, docs) {
      if (err) throw err;

      return 'Project created.';   //I want to return this string.
   });
};
```

I don't know how to return something from inside the db.collection.insert's callback function.

Comment: Res.send ("project created");

Comment: @Kevin It returns undefined in console.log().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!!

**Router.js**

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
    app.post('/create', function(req, res) {
        var create = require("./../scripts/create")(req, res, db);
    });
});
```

**Create.js**

```
module.exports = function(req, res, db) {
    db.collection('projects').insert(req.body.project, function(err, records) {
        if (err) throw err;

        res.send("Project created.");
    });
};
```

Now Angular is receiving the response from the server.

Answer (score 1):

So you have to remember that anonymous function calls in JavaScript are not assigned to anywhere. They are passed, and then lost. This is usually why we don't really have return statements in them.

`var x = function () { return y };` gives `x` the value of `y` but since there is never an assignment of the value of a callback, a return statement is meaningless. Callbacks, no matter if they have a return value, will not give you a value. They may feed that return value up to the function that they were given to, but they are entirely lost to you.

The way to get around this is to do some trickery with the scope. Basically what you want to do is 'bump' the value you want to return up a scope you can assign and then return it there. For example, you can do this:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, db) {
    var stringToReturn;
    db.collection('projects').insert(req.body.project, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) throw err;

        stringToReturn = 'Project created.';   //I want to return this string.
   });
   return stringToReturn;
};
```

This will work because the return value gets bound to module.exports, which is in turn bound to the result of

```
var create = require('./create');
console.log(create('something'))      //should log 'Project created.'
```

Comment: I tested that before but tried again. It returns undefined. And the create('something') gives an error.

Comment: Could you give us what that error is? It's most likely caused by Node executing asynchronously, stringToReturn may not always be defined when the function returns. I'll get back in a sec with a way to avoid that using your own callback

Comment: When I use your suggestion for create.js and in router.js only do: console.log(create), this returns "undefined". But, when I also use your suggestion in router.js, it means: console.log(create('something')), it return this:
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.handle (/var/www/html/dark-project/router/router.js:26:21)
    at next_layer (/var/www/html/dark-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/var/www/html/dark-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)

Comment: at c (/var/www/html/dark-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:195:24)
    at Function.proto.process_params (/var/www/html/dark-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:253:12)
    at next (/var/www/html/dark-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:19)
    at next (/var/www/html/dark-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:166:38)
    at Layer.staticMiddleware [as handle] (/var/www/html/dark-project/node_modules/express/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:66:61)

Comment: at trim_prefix (/var/www/html/dark-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:230:15)
    at c (/var/www/html/dark-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:198:9)

Comment: Right. So what's happening here is that for some reason the variable `var create = require('./create');` is not executing properly. `require('./create')` doesn't return anything. Therefore the variable `create` becomes undefined. Make sure that your `create.js` and `router.js` files are in the same folder!

Comment: They aren't. I will put them together and will come back with the result.

Comment: The same happens. It doesn't matter whether they are in the same folder. It is very strange because I have another path in router.js which calls another script, which does something very basic and return a string. Router.js receives the string in the same way: var codename = require("./../scripts/codename")(req, res, db); and show the string without problem: var console.log(codename);. But with create path, the string comes from a callback.

Comment: I made another test. router.js continues with the same code:    var create = require("./../scripts/create")(req, res, db); console.log(create);  But create.js uses the following code:    var stringToReturn = 'abc'; db.collection('projects').insert(req.body.project, function(err, docs) { if (err) throw err; stringToReturn = 'Project created.'; }); return stringToReturn;  This only returns 'abc'.